# How to create a static local variable in python instance method?

Tags: python, oop

I'm coming from a C/C++ world and am having a hard time making all of the OOP analogies in python.  I wrapped my script in a class and now get this error in my `log()` 'private' instance method:

`AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'counter'`

```
def __log(self, contents):                                                  
    sys.stdout.write(contents)                                              

    # Append all writes after the first                                     
    if not hasattr(self.__log, "counter"):                                  
        self.__log.counter = 1                                              
        f = open(self.output_filepath, 'w')                                 
    else :                                                                  
        f = open(self.output_filepath, 'a')                                 

    f.write(contents)                                                       
    f.close()
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you not use "private" names like "__log".  They are ugly, and don't actually prevent access.  Python works differently that C++.  Use it for its own sake.

Comment: They're a very strong "stay off" sign, though. As a co-developer of a major Python library, I can tell you how important it is to use underscores to signal the interface/implementation boundary to users.

Comment: Fine, use a single underscore.  Double underscores just say, "I'm used to Java or C++, and want my private keyword back!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python doesn't have static local variables.  The best solution to what you want is to use a class attribute:

```
class WithLog(object):

    opened = False

    def log(self, contents):                                                  
        sys.stdout.write(contents)                                              

        mode = "a" if self.__class__.opened else "w"
        with open(self.output_filepath, mode) as f:
            f.write(contents)       

        self.__class__.opened = True
```

Of course, it might be better not to constantly open and close the log file....

Answer (score 1):

`self.__log.counter` references to a `counter` variable which does not exist in the `__log` method.

if you need the `counter` variable to be part of the instance of the object, refer to it via `self.counter`

if you need the `counter` to be static to the class, define the variable in the class definition outside any methods. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) SO question

if you really really need the `counter` variable to be part of the instance method, the way to reference it is via `ClassName.__log.counter`

a good place to start learning OO concepts in python would be the python documentation.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score -1):

This you cant add attributes to methods, but you can modify their **dict** attribute:

```
class Test:
    def __log(self, contents):                                                  
        sys.stdout.write(contents)                                              

        # Append all writes after the first                                     
        if not "counter" in self.__log.__func__.__dict__:                                  
            self.__log.__func__.__dict__["counter"]= 1                                              
            f = open(self.output_filepath, 'w')  
            print 'w'                               
        else :                                                                  
            f = open(self.output_filepath, 'a') 
            print 'a'                               

        f.write(contents)                                                       
        f.close()  

a = Test()
a._Test__log('') #Prints w
a._Test__log('') #Prints a
b = Test()
b._Test_log('') #Prints a
```

Comment: Please, check the edit and let me know if this is what you want

Comment: Could anybody explain what's wrong whith my answer?

Comment: It's silly to add attributes to the function. Python doesn't have static local variables, you shouldn't try to force them in.  Instead, come up with a Python solution to the problem.

Comment: Well the OP wanted to add attribute to the function and I showed him how to do that. He wasnt asking for 'Pythonic' solution.

Comment: I think it's silly to give him a bad answer.  If you were reviewing his Python code, and found `self.__log.__func__.__dict__["counter"] = 1`, wouldn't you tell him to change it?